# DatabaseScheme Error when trying to install Jabber

Tags: 7, database

PROBLEM: Got the following error when trying to install Jabber. This seems like a generic error. I have a feeling that the issue is similar to this [post](http://drupal.org/node/995094). I created a [bug report](http://drupal.org/node/1794034) so the maintainer can either help or include what ever fix comes from this.

> DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table jabber already exists. in DatabaseSchema->createTable() (line 657 of public_html/d7/includes/database/schema.inc).

BACKGROUND: I have an [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) server running and was curious as to the integration with Drupal 7 and O.F. This [post](http://drupal.org/node/322243) talks about the very same thing expect.. [XMPP Framework Module](http://drupal.org/project/xmppframework) is for D6. The alternative for D7 is [Jabber](http://drupal.org/project/jabber).

I've tried both the DEV & BETA branches and both throw the same error on install. On uninstall of the module, there is another error but I've removed all entries into the DB for jabber myself.

If I try to goto the admin/settings/jabber page. It doesn't show up. Thus telling me it wasn't installed right.

How can I fix this error so the jabber module will install properly?

EDIT: After installing the DEV version. I just realized the Jabber settings page does show, although the previously mentioned error still pops. There are also additional errors but those are not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run database update then try reinstalling the module.

Also do keep backup of your database before running the update.